# Different uniform/jersey for same team in American-Football

Tags: rules, american-football, uniform

I heard that two different jerseys are used for offense and defense in american-football.

Is it so?

If yes,

- What is the reason for that?

I saw in the normal football matches that the goal-keeper worn different color jersey to differ from all others.

- so  there are three different jerseys used for a team(including goal-keeper) in american-football, am I correct?
- what about the jersey of players playing at center?

Comment: are you referring to actual match or training? Besides there's no _goal_ that a player can feasibly _keep_ in American Football. Are you sure you are not mixing things up a bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I heard that two different jerseys are used for offense and defense in
>   american-football.
>
> Is it so?

No. The whole team wears the same jerseys during the course of a game.

Given that the offense is the home team, you may be confusing the fact the offense is wearing their home jerseys (primarily their team colors) and the defense is wearing their away jerseys (primarily white). However, the offense represents one team, and the defense represents another team.

> so there are three different jerseys used for a team(including
>   goal-keeper) in american-football, am I correct?
>
> what about the jersey of players playing at center?

During an american-football contest, only one jersey is used by the entire roster of a team, no alterations. There is no specified "goal-keeper" in american football.

Comment: It's true that the whole team wears the same color/design jersey in an  American football game (vs. training activities - see [SAM's answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/3121/13730)). However, both the home and visiting teams will be playing offense and defense as the situation dictates throughout the game, generally alternating back and forth, with special teams usually appearing for one or two plays in between.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Not at all.

What I would guess is that maybe you saw a spring game which is when a football team (College level) will play a full game with their first team offense and second team defense vs. their second team offense and first team defense.  In spring games or practices (and only in spring games or practices) the same team will wear a total of three jerseys (home and away for the two teams respectively and black uniforms for the quarterbacks to signal that nobody is allowed to hit them very hard but they are considered "down" when touched.